# What is the person called whom you give a recommendation?

Tags: terminology, morphology

If person A gives person B a recommendation, can you call A *recommender* and B *recommendee*— or are these words made up?

I've seen both forms used in everyday language (e.g. magazines), but never in a dictionary or grammar book, or in literature.

Also, what is the process of creating *recommendee* or *recommender* out of *recommendation* called?

Comment: [recommendee in books](http://www.google.com/search?q=recommendee&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [recommender in dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recommender)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what kind of reference we're talking about.

*Referrals*, as suggested by @Autoresponder, is the normal term for "unsolicited" endorsements - for example, A is a satisfied customer who suggests to others that they should consider using B's products/services.

*Reference* (sometimes *referee*) is normally used in contexts where B suggest to someone that they should contact A for a "third-party" (in principle, unbiased) opinion on the quality of B's products/services.

There are many other types of recommendation, obviously. Proposing someone as the chairman of a group you're in, or as a suitable romantic attachment for your unmarried sister, for example. The list of words available for all the different contexts is too long for me to even attempt a summary.

I would say the process by which we create words such as *recommendee, recommender*, and *recommendation* from [re]commend is linguistic [production](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UVX0kkpx6h4C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=linguistic%20productive%20suffixes&source=bl&ots=NSBoo17sA2&sig=tzQ7bBAbVOkZW6VL-yMlWbkY6KM&hl=en&ei=bwOwTrPxN4qa8QPmnsyjAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=linguistic%20productive%20suffixes&f=false). The prefix **re-**, and suffixes **-ee, -er,** and **-ation** are usually referred to as *productive*. Often contrasted to other prefixes/suffixes which were used to form new words in the past, but which are no longer considered acceptable for use in generating new word forms today.

Answer (score 2):

I think of those I recommend as my *referrals*, and I recommend the word for telephonic or email contexts. I've never heard the usage *Recommendee* till now, but it's probably useful for highly formal situations / formal writing.