# Closed -> Closure, Open ->?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

Am I right in assuming that the word *closure* is derived from the word *closed*?

If so, I would be interested to know the name of this procedure and what it yields when applied to the word *open*.

My motivation is a mathematical one: "The closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing it." For certain topological spaces ([Alexandrov spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology)) it is true that every set is contained in a smallest *open* set.

Comment: For the sake of the next sentence, let me use the word "opening." Can you give an example of a mathematical statement that you would like to express about the "opening" of a set?

Comment: Be more specific in your example. My topology is really rusty, but closed and open are not antonyms (they don't share the context), so it is possible for a set to be [clopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

Comment: To help out answerers, the concept the OP is looking for is a word for the process of making something 'open'. 'Closure' is the process of making something 'closed' (e.g. 'take the closure of a set' gives you another set that is closed). So the word being sought is a process to make something have the property 'open'.

Comment: @RobinKothari: That would be "The opening of a set is the smallest open set containing it."

Answer (score 5):

My maths isn't good enough for me to grasp exactly what the [closure](https://planetmath.org/Closure) of a set actually means. In fact, I can't even tell whether it's meaningful to speak of an "opposite" in this context.

By way of example, in perspective drawing you can speak of a [vanishing point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point), but I don't think anything could meaningfully be called an "appearing point", regardless of the actual term used.

At the more general linguistic level, *closure* is effectively an alternative noun to the more common *closing*, though it's obviously acquired specialised meanings in the contexts of mathematical set theory and psychology/counselling. I don't think there's a corresponding alternative form for the "opposite" noun **opening**.

Per [my answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/what-is-the-person-called-whom-you-give-a-recommendation/46901#46901), I call the process by which we create words such as *closure* from *close* **linguistic production**. I don't know if the [**-ure** suffix](https://web.archive.org/web/20130306231530/http://www.yourdictionary.com:80/ure-suffix) is still "productive" (ie - can be used to make "new" word-forms). I suspect not, but maybe it is used for obscure new technical terms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your third paragraph seems to answer my question. The first and the second, frankly, don't help answering the question and seem off-topic to me.

Comment: Well presumably you're the mathematician, so you would know if it's mathematically meaningful to conceive of something that's the "opposite" of the "closure of a set". I don't, so the first two paragraphs are just my way of saying that, and inviting anyone who knows more about it to enlighten me. But I am reminded I never addressed your exact question "what is this lingiustic process called", so I will edit for that.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. From [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=closure&searchmode=none)

> closure 
>   late 14c., "a barrier, a fence," from O.Fr. closure "enclosure; that which encloses, fastening, hedge, wall, fence," also closture "barrier, division; enclosure, hedge, fence, wall" (12c., Mod.Fr. clôture), from L. clausura "lock, fortress, a closing" (cf. It. chiusura), from pp. stem of claudere "to close" (see close (v.)). Sense of "act of closing, bringing to a close" is from early 15c. Sense of "tendency to create ordered and satisfying wholes" is 1924, from Gestalt psychology.

Although ultimately deriving from *close*, this word was not derived from it in English, but rather came directly from French. Whether it's some standard process or not is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In English in general, the noun form of *open* is *openness*, while the noun form of *close* is *closure*.

In math, the *closure* of a set is the smallest closed set containing it. The natural mathematical antonym of closure is *interior*; the *interior* of a set is the largest open set it contains.

But what you are looking for is a word for the smallest open set containing a set. For most families of sets, this isn't a useful concept, since such a set doesn't generally exist. I don't believe there is a pre-existing word for it in the mathematical literature. In my opinion, neither of the words *opening* or *openness* is a good term for this concept. You could conscript a new word to mathematical use, and call it the *purview,* or something similar. Or you could call it the *least* (or *smallest*) *open neighborhood* of the set.

Comment: Concerning your first sentence: Isn't there also *closedness*?

Comment: @Rasmus: Googling "closedness", I find that it is much, much rarer than "openness", and that nearly all the hits are math papers talking about open and closed sets. Outside of math, I don't know whether it counts as a word. It's not in *Merriam-Webster's* online dictionary.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know that closedness is not a word.

Comment: @Rasmus: I would say *closedness* is a word, but one found only in the context of mathematics (like *abelian*).