# What is the word for someone who has been recommended?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word

Does the word *recommendee* exist? If so, is it spelled as such?

What would be the opposite, or the person who is doing the recommending?

Comment: I guess just related since I think you're asking for a slightly different thing. [What is the person called whom you give a recommendation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46874/16833)

Comment: Thanks! To give some context to the question: I'm asking about a person who recommends (recommender) a product to another person (recomendee). Spellchecker marks both of these words as incorrect.

Comment: In what context is this recommendation happening? In some contexts, *nominee* might work for the person who is recommended.

Comment: How is this question different from @Em1 's question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Recommender* is explicitly listed [in ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend?q=recommender#recommend__20), and as the *-er* suffix produces an agent noun, it's obviously someone doing the recommending.

It would be unusual to use *recommendee* as the recipient of a recommendation (although such a usage does exist with *referee*). The *-ee* form can mean such a recipient, or it can refer to a person who is being recommended; with *recommend* I would certainly expect this latter use.

Because of the ambiguity, it would be better to use a different word for both what or who is recommended (that might be *subject,* perhaps) and the person receiving the recommendation. As [the other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/what-is-the-person-called-whom-you-give-a-recommendation) implies, there is no easy way of specifying that; but for the purpose of identification you could use *recipient*.

Answer (score 1):

One could try a pseudo-Latin word **recommendand**

OED has **recommendum** from 1599, but seems unsure of its meaning

OED also has **recommendator**, but that seems to mean **recommender**

Answer (score 0):

The person who actually is recommended, let's say, as a worker to an employer, is a referee.

I am not sure on which name stands for the person making the referral, if this is what you are also asking.

But for sure the word you were looking for a person who is recommended by another person is referee.

Comment: In normal usage, the referee is the person from whom the reference is sought. That is the person to whom the potential employee is referred for an opinion. The referrer is the applicant, because he is referring the new employer to someone else. To call someone being recommended a referee is unusual to say the least.