# what should we call A and B if A gives B reference letter?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

what should we call A and B if A gives B reference letter?

A: referee?
then how about B?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/what-is-the-person-called-whom-you-give-a-recommendation

Answer (score 0):

The *-ee* suffix generally represents the *object* of an action, so I would normally say that the *referee* is *B,* not A.  This is somewhat clouded by the meaning of *referee* in sports and other contests, so I would avoid *referee* altogether as potentially confusing.

A can certainly be the *referrer,* and since a reference letter is a recommendation, could also be the *recommender;* B could be the *recommendee.*

More likely, though, I would refer to A as the *author* and to B as the *subject* of the referral, or even of the letter.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that in dictionary, referee is a person willing to testify in writing about the character or ability of someone, especially an applicant for a job...quite confused

Comment: @mia then apparently the word *referee* is already established in that meaning, and you can ignore my comment.  Although I would ask: what dictionary are you using?